# java.util.Properties - how to purge memory on demand

Tags: java

I am running a swing application in which I am getting all the labels, errors, etc. from  property file. I have 2 huge global property files for error messages and labels. Huge means - 150kb.

Also there are smaller property files and xml files which are cached. They are not big but they might all add up in the end culminating to an OutOfMemory when running on a system with less than 1 GB RAM.

I was wondering how do you dispose of the smaller Properties object once you have used it. When you set the object to null, and once the GC runs it will go away. Is there another way where we are guaranteed that the cached properties are purged when needed by an API call?

Comment: "Huge means - 150kb".... seriously?  huge?

Comment: No, there isn't. The only option you might have is to build a native library to handle your properties file and call it from your Java code, then you will be able to remove them from memory when not needed.

Comment: Are you getting an `OutOfMemoryError`. Why do you think you will?

Comment: The question was more out of preventing something like this in the future. This a big swing application with many swing objects already. On top of that property files will just add to it. So I am just trying to code it efficiently right now rather hit issues tomorrow. The application caches properties, xmls, db data and it can be deployed on systems with RAM as low as 512MB. With the antivirus and other applications running the swing app might just run out of memory if I dont code efficiently right now

Comment: @Skaffman the swing app is already occupying 250MB RAM... Hence thought I need to cut corners now.

Comment: @sethu: So get yourself a profiler and find out where the memory is really going. Cutting out a 150kb properties file is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

What about this method: [Clearing properties cache](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#clearCache%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29)